# How to display list of friends with its corresponding profile picture using Facebook API php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I was able to get the list of friends but not their respective profile picture.

Sample output: == LIST OF FRIENDS ==
Total friends: 927.

//Dislay friends here but no profile picture.

```
<?php
  $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

  echo "=== LIST OF FRIENDS ===";
  echo "<br/>";


  $total_friends = count($friends['data']);


  echo 'Total friends: '.$total_friends.'.<br />';
  $start = 0;
  echo '<br />';
  while ($start < $total_friends) {
    echo $friends['data'][$start]['name'];
?>

<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/picture"/>

<?php
  echo $value["data"][$start]['name'];
?>

<?php
    echo '<br />';
    $start++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have to output the user id or username in the image URL …

Comment: Please explain more specifically--what results are you getting and how do they differ from the desired results?  BTW, notice that you're superfluously closing and immediately reopening your script tags toward the end. Easier to see when your code is formatted properly, hint, hint... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get friends image directly in IMG tag as

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{idfriend}/picture?type=square"/>
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{idfriend}/picture?type=small"/>
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{idfriend}/picture?type=normal"/>
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{idfriend}/picture?type=large"/>
```